# Syntactic Information of an Emacs Buffer

Tags: emacs, syntax, buffer

I'm currently implementing **Clustered Query-Replace** in Emacs. Clustering should be sensitive to

1. case,
2. symbol and word context and
3. whether hit is plain code, inside a comment or part of a string literal

The first two points are easy to make efficient. The last point requires an efficient way to extract *all* the mode-syntax-specific (`syntax-table`) comment- and string-regions of an Emacs buffer. I know of `syntax-ppss` but I want a faster way to get all regions. Is there a built-in function for that or do I have to *manually* search for each string and comment beginning-end *pair*. I don't want to depend on `font-lock` because that is too slow for my application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Great question, and neat project! I don't have the knowledge to help you with your question, but I am interested to see how this works when you finish it. Are you planning on submitting this to ELPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that 'skip-syntax-forward' does what you want.

Comment: Is `syntax-ppss` only for emacs-lisp-mode, then?

Comment: No, it should work in all modes. In fact, ignore my original answer for now, 'syntax-ppss' and 'parse-partial-sexp' is probably the way to go. I've written similar things in the past and I'm willing to help, so please keep me posted on how you get along.

Comment: `syntax-ppss-contest` does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the CEDET tool suite available, you could use the lexical analyze that comes with the Semantic tool to do this work.  All supported modes have a lexer, but these lexers usually ignore comments.  Creating new lexical analyzers that just handle comments and strings isn't hard, and there is an example that does this for handling tag documentation in `semantic-doc-snarf-comment-for-tag`.

Whats nice about the lexical analyzer is it gives you a list of lexical tokens which you can filter through in a simple way.